# Insert multiple files on database c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm creating a *winform* application in c# for archiving documents,images, videos etc. into SQL Server. Till now i've been able to select files from *opendialog* and save the path of selected documents into a *listbox*. Here is the code:

```
    public void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
        dlg.Multiselect = true;
        dlg.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*";

        DialogResult dlgRes = dlg.ShowDialog();
        if (dlgRes == DialogResult.OK)
        {

            foreach (String file in dlg.FileNames)
            {

                listBox1.Items.Add(file);
            }
        }

    }
```

What i want to do now is to insert to database all documents that are selected on *OpenFileDialog*. 
**EDIT**
Here is my code to insert file to database.

```
 byte[] ReadFile(string sPath)
    {
        //Initialize byte array with a null value initially.
        byte[] data = null;

        //Use FileInfo object to get file size.
        FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(sPath);
        long numBytes = fInfo.Length;

        //Open FileStream to read file
        FileStream fStream = new FileStream(sPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

        //Use BinaryReader to read file stream into byte array.
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fStream);

        //When you use BinaryReader, you need to supply number of bytes to read from file.
        //In this case we want to read entire file. So supplying total number of bytes.
        data = br.ReadBytes((int)numBytes);

        //Close BinaryReader
        br.Close();

        //Close FileStream
        fStream.Close();

        return data;
    }

    private void btnDocAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var myOtherList = listBox1.Items.Cast<String>().ToList();

        foreach (var f in myOtherList)
        {

            byte[] FileData = ReadFile(f);
            string path = Path.GetFileName(f);
            //Set insert query

            string qry = @"Insert into FilesStore (Linja, Magazina, Arkiva, OriginalPath,FileData,Lloji, Data,NrProt, EmriDok,Perdoruesi) values(@linja,@magazina,@arkiva,@OriginalPath, @FileData, @lloji, @Data,@nrprot, @emr,@perdoru)";

            //Initialize SqlCommand object for insert.
            SqlCommand SqlCom = new SqlCommand(qry, con);
            DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;              // Use current time
            string format = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss";    // modify the format depending upon input required in the column in database 
                                                      // string insert = @" insert into Table(DateTime Column) values ('" + dt.ToString(format) + "')";
                                                      //We are passing Original File Path and File byte data as sql parameters.

            SqlCom.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@linja", (object)cbLinja.Text));
            SqlCom.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@magazina", (object)cbDokMagazina.Text));
            SqlCom.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@arkiva", (object)cbArkiv.Text));
            SqlCom.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@OriginalPath", (object)f));
            SqlCom.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FileData", (object)FileData));
            SqlCom.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@lloji", (object)cbLloji.Text));
            SqlCom.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Data", (object)dt.ToString(format)));
            SqlCom.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@nrprot", (object)txtDocProt.Text));
            SqlCom.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@emr", (object)Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path)));
            SqlCom.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@perdoru", (object)lblPerd.Text));

            con.Open();

            SqlCom.ExecuteNonQuery();

            con.Close();
```

When i add the documents one by one it works fine. But when i try to add multiple documents it only adds one document x times (x = number of items on listbox)

Comment: Then show your SQL code, show whats not working

Comment: `dlg.FileNames` already contains the list of documents (filenames, not file content). That much should be clear from the intent of the code you posted. If you are asking how to save something in the database, you'll have to show a code example of how you intend to add it to your database.

Comment: Did you checked with debug `myOtherList` what's inside?

Comment: there are the paths of each document selected.i have it visible on the form. There is another problem..when i set a break point to execute the code line by line it works fine for all the document..

Comment: where is the data for your parameters coming from? e.g. `(object)cbLinja.Text` or `(object)cbDokMagazina.Text`. They aren't defined in your code. It seems like this will add the same data into these parameters on every loop. Only the value of `f` and `FileData` will vary. Is that what you want? Seems like you are adding multiple documents but with identical metadata for each document.

Comment: I only focused on the `f` and `FileData` variables which are correctly handled. But ADyson is correct, the parameters are set from what appears to be `TextBox`es and `ComboBox`es. For each file you are using the same controls there, so obviously you'll get the same data...

Comment: @ADyson there are different documents that are part of the same category . all the objects that has "cb" in front are comboboxes

Comment: in that case you really want to have a separate table for the documents. Repeating identical metadata every time is creating denormalised, redundant data. The correct database structure would be to define the metadata in a single row in a parent table and then have a Documents table with a foreign key to the row in the metadata table. I realise that's not solving your issue directly but it will give you a cleaner and more maintainable database.

Answer (score 0):

The following does not employ the OpenDialog but instead I simple select all images in a folder below the app debug folder which is of course hard-coded yet the idea is simply to get images files which you do via the OpenDialog. Think of this as a simulation.

Form code (which calls a method in a class found below) where here I populate files and when inserting images get the new primary key also, this is to show the insert worked. In a real app we would return the changed list, here I'm not.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var location = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Images");
            List<ImageItem> imageItemsList = (
                from file in Directory.GetFiles(location)
                select new ImageItem
                {
                        Name = Path.GetFileName(file),
                        Bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(file),
                        Description = "Inserted from code sample"
                    }
                ).ToList();

            DatabaseImageOperations ops = new DatabaseImageOperations();
            ops.InsertImages(imageItemsList);
        }
    }
}
```

Data operations class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public class DatabaseImageOperations
{
    private string databaseServer = @".\SQLEXPRESS";
    private string defaultCatalog = "ImageData1";
    private string _ConnectionString;
    private string ConnectionString
    {
        get
        {
            return _ConnectionString;
        }
        set
        {
            _ConnectionString = value;
        }
    }
    public DatabaseImageOperations()
    {
        _ConnectionString = $"Data Source={databaseServer};Initial Catalog={defaultCatalog};Integrated Security=True";
    }
    public void InsertImages(List<ImageItem> Images)
    {
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection { ConnectionString = ConnectionString })
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand { Connection = cn })
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ImageData (ImageData, [Description]) " + 
                                  "VALUES  (@img, @description);SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int);";

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@img", SqlDbType.Image);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@description", SqlDbType.Text);

                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter
                {
                    ParameterName = "@new_identity",
                    SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int,
                    Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
                });

                cn.Open();

                foreach (ImageItem item in Images)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters["@img"].Value = item.Bytes;
                    cmd.Parameters["@description"].Value = item.Description;
                    item.Id = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Class to stored file info.

```
public class ImageItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public byte[] Bytes { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Table structure

```
USE [ImageData1]
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ImageData](
    [ImageID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ImageData] [image] NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ImageData] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ImageID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Hopefully this helps pattern wise which you could adapt to your task. 
[image]

**Edit**:
Here is a version (still no open dialog) that uses a ListBox

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var location = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Images");
            List<ImageItem> imageItemsList = (
                from file in Directory.GetFiles(location)
                select new ImageItem
                {
                        Name = Path.GetFileName(file),
                        Bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(file),
                        Description = "Inserted from code sample"
                    }
                ).ToList();

            listBox1.DataSource = imageItemsList;
            listBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";

        }
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             var imageItemsList = (List<ImageItem>)listBox1.DataSource;
            DatabaseImageOperations ops = new DatabaseImageOperations();
            ops.InsertImages(ref imageItemsList);
        }
    }
}
```

Small modification to the data class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public class DatabaseImageOperations
{
    private string databaseServer = @"L-36007\SQLEXPRESS";
    private string defaultCatalog = "ImageData1";
    private string _ConnectionString;
    private string ConnectionString
    {
        get
        {
            return _ConnectionString;
        }
        set
        {
            _ConnectionString = value;
        }
    }
    public DatabaseImageOperations()
    {
        _ConnectionString = $"Data Source={databaseServer};Initial Catalog={defaultCatalog};Integrated Security=True";
    }
    public void InsertImages(ref List<ImageItem> Images)
    {
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection { ConnectionString = ConnectionString })
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand { Connection = cn })
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ImageData (ImageData, [Description]) " + 
                                  "VALUES  (@img, @description);SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int);";

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@img", SqlDbType.Image);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@description", SqlDbType.Text);

                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter
                {
                    ParameterName = "@new_identity",
                    SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int,
                    Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
                });

                cn.Open();

                foreach (ImageItem item in Images)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters["@img"].Value = item.Bytes;
                    cmd.Parameters["@description"].Value = item.Description;
                    item.Id = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

you can save all the paths together in a same column as comma separated and split them to a list while retrieving from DB.

to Join all the path together:

```
var DBValue = string.Join(",", listBox1.Items.Cast<String>().ToList())
```

to retrieve from DB:

```
var ListofAttachments= DBValue.Split(',').ToList<string>();
```

Comment: yuk, this just makes messy de-normalised data. Far better to have a separate table to list each one. Then it's queryable.

Comment: @ADyson what will happen if he tries to add more than 1000 attachments from 5 different listboxes does he need to insert 5000 records in a separate table ?

Comment: yes. It's not a lot in database terms. in recent SQL Server it can be done in one INSERT statement. Any in your example you're only adding strings not the actual files. But in any case, ask yourself how likely it is there will be 1000 attachments selected by a user in one request? And who said anything about multiple listboxes? You're making some rather extreme assumptions. Also, if you're worried about extreme numbers, your solution has a hard limit on how many names can be stored. If the field size is `max`, it's a very high limit, but still a limit. A 2nd table has no practical limit.

Comment: yes Thanks @ADyson, i thought of using a single table instead of going for a second table, so will reverse my approach on this and follow as you suggested